# allocating specific training subset to specific classifier for ensemble mode

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bootstrap, bagging

I have a dataset I'd like to break into 2 to 3 subsets to account for outliers. Train the subsets with individual classifier and combining them. Understand that Bagging uses subset of the base training set. However, it is randomly selected for each classifier.

Therefore, is it possible to allocate specific training subset to specific classifier for Bagging or is there any ensemble mode that is able to allocate specific training subset to specific classifier.

ps. not sure whether the question fits here or stackoverflow, hence, if necessary kindly let me know whether to relocate the question. Thank you